# Oracle SQL Left and right outer Join with/Without where clause giving different outputs

Tags: oracle, join, where-clause

Why is there a difference in output for the below queries?

As per my understanding it should give the same output for the first 3 queries and same output for the last 3 queries.

```
select count(*) 
from CTM_People a left outer join user_x b 
     on a.remedy_login_id = b.login_name;
```

**Result 1: 152771**

```
select count(*) 
from CTM_People a left outer join user_x b 
     on a.remedy_login_id = b.login_name 
where a.remedy_login_id like '%';
```

**Result 2: 151185**

```
select count(*) 
from CTM_People a left outer join user_x b 
     on a.remedy_login_id = b.login_name and a.remedy_login_id like '%';
```

**Result 3: 152771**

```
select count(*) 
from CTM_People a right outer join user_x b 
     on a.remedy_login_id = b.login_name;
```

**Result 1: 150899**

```
select count(*) 
from CTM_People a right outer join user_x b 
     on a.remedy_login_id = b.login_name where a.remedy_login_id like '%';
```

**Result 2: 150889**

```
select count(*) 
from CTM_People a right outer join user_x b 
     on a.remedy_login_id = b.login_name and a.remedy_login_id like '%';
```

**Result 3: 150899**

Total count in both the tables are

```
select count(*) from CTM_People; **Result : 152771**
select count(*) from user_x; **Result : 150899**
```

Comment: LIKE operator doesn't accept NULLs. Do you have any NULL values in a.remedy_login_id?

Comment: If you're using Oracle, please adjust your tags and remove MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: There's probably null values like @DavidP mentioned, 3rd isn't affected because the '%' is the outer join criteria and the other difference depends on which table you outer join.

Comment: Thanks David and James. I got it. CTM_People table actually had 1586 null values.

Comment: I added my previous comment as an answer so you can accept or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE operator doesn't accept NULLs. Please check a.remedy_login_id